# The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'

Tags: firebase, flutter, snackbar, flutter-dropdownbutton

Here i create a DropdownItemMenu which get the element from firebase collection, but it shows me an error

> The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'

```
Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.10,
                    child: Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          isExpanded: false,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14, color: Colors.blueGrey),
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                          underline: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
                          onChanged: (serieValue) {
                            final snackBar = SnackBar(
                                content: Text(
                              'Série selectionnée est $serieValue',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                            ));
                            Scaffold.of(context.showSnackBar(snackBar));


                            setState(() {
                              selectedIndexSerie = serieValue;
                            });
                          },
                          value: selectedIndexSerie,
                          hint: Text(
                            'Selectionner une série',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                          ),
                          items: series,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
```

Answer (score 59):

You misplaced a ')' -->

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Also, showSnackBar is deprecated, consider using ScaffoldMessenger

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the ScaffoldMessenger option, fixed my problem.

Answer (score 15):

Verify in flutter 3.7.1:

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

->

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar
```

Answer (score 2):

In flutter 3.0 and later versions show `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);` as Depreciated. Instead use `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar)`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem by

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

That's your line of code: `Scaffold.of(context.showSnackBar(snackBar));` You have to put the capital 'S'; would look like this: `Scaffold.of(context.showSnackBar(SnackBar));`